# Preference of TestFlight over Apple Enterprise Developer Program

Tags: ios, testflight, iphone-developer-program

Like most of us considering TestFlight (recently bought by Apple) and Apple Enterprise Developer Program, I am hoping to let users download my app without UDID hassle.

Considering Apple just bought TestFlight and setting up of TestFlight is easier than Apple Enterprise Developer Program, do you think I would be able to let users download my app without any UDID requirement with TestFlight?

Added benefit of TestFlight is that it can allow up to 2,000 users to download the app compared to 100 for Enterprise program.
EDIT: Enterprise program can allow unlimited user. Guess this can change to cost of $300 for Enterprise program.

I'll be grateful if any of you can comment on this and if there's some hidden loophole that I am not aware of.

Should I use TestFlight over Enterprise Program to ensure my users would be able to download the app without any hassle?

Comment: Enterprise is unlimited. The 100 limit is for the non-enterprise account. All the user needs is a special sort of link to a special sort of plist.

Comment: May be I am not understanding correctly, but at the end of the page, it mentions 100. https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

Comment: That's for installing directly to the device **from Xcode**. None of your beta/alpha testers need that. Just your devs.

Comment: Importantly, enterprise accounts can install to non-provisioned devices, just can't *build* to non-provisioned devices--**no one can build to non-provisioned devices**.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Now for my original question. Would TestFlight be preferred in my case and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TestFlight. The Enterprise program is for in-house users and devices only, not external ones. This is a legal limitation of the program, not a technical one.